# Google Chrome dev tools not showing the correct "this"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools

If I run this script in Chrome and put a break point on line 3, then inspect, `this` is shown to be `obj`. However, when you step through, `Window` gets logged to the console.

If you change `method` to a regular arrow function (remove `async`), `this` is `undefinied` when inspected, and `Window` when logged (I think this is normal behaviour?). I have no idea what's going on here. Seems like a bug but I know better than to assume that.

```
let obj = {
    method: async()=>{
        console.log(this); //break point here
    },
};

obj.method();
```

Comment: Huh, that's weird. I tried to inspect but it always says `Window` object, which the expecting result.

Comment: @HaoWu I'm using version 74.0.3729.169 on Windows 10, what about yourself?

Comment: Same here but on Mac. Well, I guess because of arrow functions doesn't have `this` assigned so maybe it could be behaving a little bit weird during runtime while the `this` get inspected by the debugger.

Comment: Are you using Babel, or running this as actual code? You haven't mentioned.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm running that exact code form a an html document that's just `<script scr='test.js'></script>`